# Error while updating mongodatabase collections from django app using djongo

Tags: python, sql, django, sql-parser, djongo

I am facing an error. I am trying out the polls tutorial as provided in the django documentation. The problem is with the django 'F' function. I am trying to update the number of votes for a choice. If I load the choice object into python memory and do the normal numeric addition it is working. But if I use `choice.update(votes=F('votes')+1)` then it is giving me the following error.

```
djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: UPDATE "poll_choice" SET "question_id" = %(0)s, "choice_text" = %(1)s, "votes" = ("poll_choice"."votes" + %(2)s) WHERE "poll_choice"."id" = %(3)s
```

Params: (1, 'huntress', 1, 3)

If we observe `%(2)s` is supposed to be a number and not a string. 
But it is going as a string.
Please help how I can resolve this .
I am using djongo 1.2.38 with sqlparse version 0.2.4.

Comment: Where are you importing `F` from? djongo provides it's own F class

Comment: I am importing F class from `django.db.models` package.